# Webpack, DedupePlugin not work with code split and ProvidePlugin?

Tags: webpack

Here is `webpack` `ProvidePlugin` config:

```js
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  util: path.join(src, 'util.js'),
  API: path.join(src, 'api.js')
});
```

After compiling, there are many `chunks` in `dist` directory of my project.

Each `chunk` use `API` and `Util` and each `chunk` has the `API` and `Util` code. It seems `DedupePlugin` not working.

I want to extract the `API` and `Util` to a single `chunk` or add to the entry `bundle` file.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for the CommonsChunkPlugin

```
entry: {
 api: path.join(src, 'api.js'),
 utils: path.join(src, 'util.js'),
 app: "./entry"
}

...

new CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: "commons",
  // (the commons chunk name)

  filename: "commons.js",
  // (the filename of the commons chunk)

  chunks: ["api", "util"],
  // (Only use these entries)
})
```

Just make sure you load the common chunk before your main app

```
<script src="commons.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="entry.bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, Thanks. But I want to use `ProvidePlugin ` to provide global module variable.
And do not want to put the `api` and `util` to entry.

Comment: I think there is unneccssary to use ` CommonsChunkPlugin` , just set this: `entry: { commons: ['api', 'util'] }`, but for my case, the `CommonsChunkPlugin` `options.chunks` may be` ['1.chunk', '2.chunk', '3.chunk'....]`.